# Finding a repeated pattern in a string

Tags: java, string, character

How can I find a repeated pattern in a string? For example, if the input file were

```
AAAAAAAAA
ABABAB
ABCAB
ABAb
```

it would output:

```
A
AB
ABCAB
ABAb
```

Comment: What if the string is `"AABB"`. What's the expected output?

Comment: `AABB`. The repeat has to go all the way from the start to end, otherwise, return the whole string.

Comment: @BelgianMyWaffle I don't think this is a duplicate. If I understood the question well, its about repeated pattern in string, not character.

Comment: If the string is AABB, then the output would be AABB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This outputs what you ask for - the regex can probably be improved to avoid the loop but I can't manage to fix it...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList("AAAAAAAAA", "ABABAB", "ABCAB", "ABAb");
    for (String s : inputs) System.out.println(findPattern(s));
}

private static String findPattern(String s) {
    String output = s;
    String temp;
    while (true) {
        temp = output.replaceAll("(.+)\\1", "$1");
        if (temp.equals(output)) break;
        output = temp;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: @Bohemian Can someone please explain me the regex part alone? ("(.+)\\1", "$1")

Comment: @santhoshkumar see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21962028/256196) for an explanation of the regex

Answer (score 10):

If you use regex, you only need one line:

```
String repeated = str.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "$1");
```

Breaking down the regex `(.+?)\1`:

- `(.+?)` means "at least one character, but as few as possible, captured as group 1"
- `\1` means "the same character(s) as group 1

---

Here's some test code:

```
String[] strs = {"AAAAAAAAA", "ABABAB", "ABCAB", "ABAb"};
for (String str : strs) {
    String repeated = str.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "$1");
    System.out.println(repeated);
}
```

Output:

```
A
AB
ABCAB
ABAb
```

Comment: @santhoshkumar depends what you mean by "works". What result do you expect from `AAAAAAB`?

Comment: Oops.., Sorry for not being clear. For example.., "AAAAAAB" i need output as "AAAAAAB" but this is returning "AB". How i can tweak this?

Comment: @Bohemian What would be the time complexity of this? Not sure how regex works with something like this, but I imagine multiple scans?

Comment: @TheRealFakeNews time complexity is approx O(n log n): There is only one pass, but there is some re-checking of following chars along the way as the quantity of `.+?` grows. If long sequences were expected to be repeated, the greedier `.+` may be faster.

Comment: @Bohemian How is it you came to nlogn?

Answer (score 1):

Written in C#, but translation should be trivial.

```
public static string FindPattern(string s)
{
    for (int length = 1; length <= s.Length / 2; length++)
    {
        string pattern = s.Substring(0, length);
        if(MatchesPattern(s, pattern))
        {
            return pattern;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

public static bool MatchesPattern(string s, string pattern)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if(!s[i].Equals(pattern[i%pattern.Length]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you might have spaces between the repeated segment:

```
(.+?)(\\ ?\\1)+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yon don't need reexp to find pattern.  Knuth-Morris-Pratt KMP Algorithm can do this much faster.

```
func getPattern(s string) string {
   res := make([]int, len(s)+1)

   i := 0
   j := -1
   res[0] = -1

   var patternLength int
   for i < len(s) {
       if j == -1 || s[i] == s[j] {
           i++
           j++
           res[i] = j
           if res[i] == 0 {
               patternLength++
           } else {
               break
           }
       } else {
           j = res[j]
       }
   }
   if patternLength == len(s) {
       patternLength = 0
   }
   return s[:patternLength]
}
```

**Unit Tests**

```
func Test_getPattern(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        str1     string
        expected string
    }{
        {"AAAAAAAAA", "A"},
        {"ABCABC", "ABC"},
        {"ABABAB", "AB"},
        {"LEET", ""},
    }

    for _, tc := range testCases {
        actual := getPattern(tc.str1)
        if tc.expected != actual {
            t.Errorf("Source: s1:%s\n   Expected:%s\n   Actual:  %s",
                tc.str1,
                tc.expected,
                actual)
        }
    }
}
```