# Finding the exponent of a string

Tags: java, regex, java-8, pattern-matching

I got this problem in my programming competency test. I need to find the exponent of a string.

For Eg :

- Input `Str = "pctpctpct"`, output : `pct 3`.
- Input `str : "pressure"`,  output `0`. Because pressure is not repeating as a string.

That is the string pct is repeated 3 times. 
I need to create a method for this. I tried everything but failed. 
My method was :

```
public static int findExponent(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    String subs = "";
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= str.length() / 2; j++) {
            subs = str.substring(i, j);
            al.add(subs);
            System.out.println(al);
            for (String x : al)
                for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++) {
                    if (str.contains(x)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here I was checking if any substring matches the pattern of the String. But it is not giving me the correct output. What changes should I need to do in this?

How to check the pattern for such a type of question where we have to create a pattern and check if it's repeated?

Comment: *I tried everything but failed*. Could you please share your best effort?

Comment: Should not `pressure` output `pressure 1`?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a meaningful problem statement. Please [edit] your question to include the details of *how* your program doesn't work (a [mcve] would be ideal).

Comment: Share your tries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding a repeated pattern in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961729/finding-a-repeated-pattern-in-a-string)

Comment: What should be result for `aaaa`? Should it be considered as `(a)(a)(a)(a) = a^4` so result would be `4` OR `(aa)(aa) = (aa)^2` which would result in `2`?

Comment: @jrook my best approach was this

Comment: public static int findExponent(String str) {
  int count = 0;
  String subs = "";
  ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i++) {
   for (int j = i + 1; j <= str.length() / 2; j++) {
    subs = str.substring(i, j);
    al.add(subs);
    System.out.println(al);
    for (String x : al)
     for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++) {
      if (str.contains(x)) {
       count++;
      }
     }
   }
  }
  return count;
 }

Answer (score 0):

How about this. I would go ahead with the algorithm based on java:-

```
Lets assume the input is the string
convert it to character sequence (array of char)
Sort the array into a temp array
loop from 0 to array length
count the ith letter repetition
if its 0
    return 0;
else 
    if count for all word matches
        return count;
```

complexity is 0(n) and this code would work